# передача List<String> в другую активити

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api

Как передать `List<String>list= new ArrayList<>()` в другую активити? Ну или в ViewPager?

Comment: Любой объект (проще говоря, все, что  не является простым типом аля `int` можно) передать через интерфейс `parcelable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам надо поместить ваш список сторок в Intent, коий вы запускаете вторую активити с помощью метода `Intent#putStringArrayListExtra(String key, ArrayList<String> list)`. Потом, во второй активити вам надо по ключу вытащить этот список из интенета.

В первой активити:

```
ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();
ar.add("Apple");
ar.add("Banana");

Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivityClassName.class);
i.putStringArrayListExtra("list", ar);
startActivity(i);
```

Во второй:

```
ArrayList<String> ar1 = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("list");
```

Comment: так у меня List<String> и ругается на imgUrls в intent.putStringArrayListExtra("image", imgUrls);

Comment: @sviter-pro, ваше сообщение неинформативно - без указания типа ошибки и примера проблеммного кода в вопросе помочь вам никак нельзя