# Передача обьекта между активити

Tags: android, android-intent

Как передать токен в другое активити, который был получен через Call?

Я создал запрос на получение логина, запустил запрос и получил токен. Нужно его передать в другое активити для отображения там инфы полученной с api.

Comment: Токен как-то отличается от всего остального, что его нельзя передать обычным способом через экстрас?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [передача List<String> в другую активити](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/567110/%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-liststring-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8)

Answer (score 3):

Самый простой способ это передать его в `intent`. Небольшой пример отправки:

```
public static final String TOKEN_KEY = "token_key";
...
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class); 
intent.putExtra(TOKEN_KEY, token);
startActivity(intent);
```

Получение данных в другой активности:

```
String yourToken = intent.getStringExtra(TOKEN_KEY);
```